# Save operation not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, save

I am trying to perform `save` a collection in `mongo db` using the  `node.js` driver.I use the following code:

```
 require("mongodb").MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/course",function(db,err){
if(err) console.log(err);
else{
    var query={"assignment":"hw2"};
    db.collection("grades").findOne(query,function(err,doc){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else{
            //console.dir(doc);
            doc["date_returned"]=new Date();
            db.collection("grades").save(doc,function(err,saved){
                if(err) console.log(err);
                else{
                    console.log("Successfully saved "+saved+" documents");
                    return db.close();
                }

            });
        }

    });
}
```

});

I get this huge error which I put in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zwW2FnzB)

Comment: I think you reversed the parameters in your first callback. You have function(db,err) but it should be function(err, db)

Comment: Which line gives the error? The load or the save line, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the callback of the `.connect` function. You exchanged the error with the result in the argument positions, so you are printing the database object instead the error. It should be:

```
.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/course",function(err,db){
```